# Australian Tourist visa - apply from India and travel from USA

Tags: visas, usa, india, australia, tourist-visas

I hold an Indian passport but I reside in USA, I will be in India for a month, can I apply for Australian Tourist Visa in India and travel to Australia from USA ??

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are.  Unlike many countries, the Australian government clears all visa holders prior to boarding using their world-wide system. You can tell them your itinerary when you apply, but it doesn't make much difference.  All carriers landing in Australia must have a registration on their system.  See https://www.immi.gov.au/managing-australias-borders/border-security/air/checkin.htm

Comment: @pnuts, it seemed too simple, but if nobody takes a shot, then I can convert it. The Aussies have their act together!

Comment: @pnuts: FWIW, I tried to do some of the online research the OP should have done, but came away somewhat empty-handed. India is one of the few nationalities for which Australia _doesn't_ accept _online_ tourist visa applications, but Australia's consular websites don't say much about where and how Indians residing outside India are supposed to file their paper application. Everything outside the high commission (embassy) in New Delhi just point prospective tourists towards the online application process.

Answer (score 2):

Once a visa is issued - you can travel from any country to the country that issued you the visa.

This is a general rule and the only restriction that I know of (which does not apply to your situation) is when emergency travel documents are issued; or in some cases - special visas are issued that define the mode of travel (for example, if your Saudi Arabian visa states that you are to travel by land, you cannot fly to certain airports).

In addition, as Gayot mentioned in his comment some countries allow you to check-in before you travel (its not just Australia - travelers to the US can [check-in and clear immigration at Abu Dhabi](http://www.etihad.com/en-us/before-you-fly/us-preclearance/) for example) - airlines now have to provide advance passenger information ([APIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System)) and this includes your passport details.

In summary - get your visa issued from India, travel back to the US and you can then travel to Australia. Good luck and enjoy your trip!

Comment: Since OP is a national of India but a _resident_ of the US, it may be that Australia requires that he lodge his visa application in his country of _residence_, like many countries do. I haven't been able to find any information for or against this on the net, but when you say "get your visa issued from India", do you have positive knowledge that he'll be able to do that?

Comment: Specifically for Australia I know that you are required to request the visa from your country of citizenship not residence as recently faced by my brother.

Comment: x @Burhan: That would probably be a valuable addition to the answer.

Comment: Not really because the OP will be applying for the visa from India, the question is if I apply from India do I have to start my journey to Australia from India and the answer to that is No.